# Sonar+ReSharper with projects containing linked files

Tags: c#, resharper, sonarqube

I have a Visual Studio / C# solution containing several projects. Some of the projects have links to source code in other directories (shared code that is used in several projects).

When running Sonar it seems to work well (although I'm not sure that it actually works!), and when running ReSharper outside Sonar it also works well. However, when running ReSharper from Sonar, then I end up with a lot of 
17:44:37.607 INFO  - Skipping the ReSharper issue at line 6259 whose file "C:\GitRepos\myProject\Code\Shared.All\Core\StorageSqlCe.cs" is not in SonarQube.
(This is when I'm analysing the C:\GitRepos\myProject\Code\Server\ project)

It's not really a multi-module project (since I don't want to analyse all of the Shared.All directory - only the files that are linked from my project (Server in this case).

Does anyone know how to deal with this? If I were to ignore what's in each project and do analysis of the Shared.All folder I would fail with ReSharper since I have no VS-project file there...

I can't change the project structure of the code. And the design to have shared code in special folders might not be the best, but that is a design that was made a long time ago that we have to live with. So, how can I work with Sonar on this?

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand you, you have one shared folder, located on the filesystem at the same level as your projects:

- Solution.sln
- Project1\

  - ...
- Project2\

  - ...
- Shared\

  - ...

If you are using the Visual Studio Bootstrapper plugin, you are always analyzing a multi-module project: Each Visual Studio Project becomes a SonarQube module. A main project (with no sources) is created for the solution itself.

There is a limitation in SonarQube: All sources of a module must be located within the module's folder, for example for the computation of relative paths (etc.) to work properly.

The "Shared" folder in your case does not belong to any project, and hence cannot be imported in SonarQube.

You have several options:

1. Accept that the shared code is not being analyzed in SonarQube
2. No longer rely on the Visual Studio Bootstrapper plugin, and analyze the whole solution as a single SonarQube project. But you will then hit other limitations (such as https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARFXCOP-36)

I would recommend you option 1 for the short term, while waiting for this ticket on the Visual Studio Bootstrapper to no longer create SonarQube modules to be implemented: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARVS-59